# Cannot enter if loop at bash script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, scripting, directory

I want to create one bash script that takes as argument a directory from the command line and prints all my subdirectories. My script prints all the files that this directory has and does not enter in the if loop. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo to argv[1] = $1
if [ -e $1 ] #exist the file
then if [ -d $1 ] # is directory
    then if [ -r $1 ] #we can read
        then for k in $(ls $1) #all the files in the arv[1] 
        do
            echo $k #print all the files of directory
            if [ -d $k ]
                then echo $k
            fi
        done
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ -d $k ]` tests whether $k is a directory **relative to the current working directory**, but you need to use

```
[ -d "$1/$k" ]
```

instead.

Also, instead of iterating over the output of `ls`, use

```
for k in $1/*
```

which makes the above change needless.

BTW, `while`, `until`, and `for` start a loop, but `if` doesn't. I'd call it an "if block".